# what questionnaire will i use to compare 2 website interface designs?

Tags: website-design

I had developed now 2 website lay-out for my thesis.
Now i am trying to compare those 2 websites based on their design with the aid of questionnaires. what questionnaires will i use to compare the 2 websites user interface design not the usability of the 2 websites.

Answer (score 1):

## Focus on the message not the design

You can't survey people about what they think of a design. A general audience is only going to give you misleading information.

When comparing visual solutions, you have to focus on impressions. Shape your question to gain insight into what each design tells the viewer and how it makes them feel. Questions like:

> Would you expect this service to be ...
> [ ] Expensive
> [ ] Reasonably priced
> [ ] Cheap
>
> Is this company ...
> [ ] Stuffy
> [ ] Professional
> [ ] Casual
> [ ] Hipster

**Craft questions that validate whether or not you're sending the desired message.** It may be value, emotion, style, craftsmanship, or reliability. You want to see which design delivers that message best.